# Thymeleaf does not take localization in th:include

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

I trying to use Spring's localization bundle with Thymeleaf templates. It works well if it is used in normal templates, but fails if I apply th:include attribute at container tag.

I put the view code to Gist: https://gist.github.com/hron84/386bbf855148a601a3dc

The problematic localization is at line 4 and line 10. In the line 10 I see the correct expansion ("New machine") but in line 4, i just get "null" as the page title.

Could you please point me what do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin says, your th:include is replacing your title tag, you should do somthing like this:

```
<head>
    <title th:text="#{page.title.machine.new}">&nbsp;</title>
    <dif th:include="widgets/_head :: head" th:remove="tag"></dif>
</head>
```

The th:remove="tag" will remove the dif tag.

The Thymeleaf website has some usefull [documentation about the th:include and th:replace tags](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinclude-and-threplace).

Answer (score 0):

With th:include your are replacing the inner conten, ie the title tag, with the content fetched from the fragment. As you did not post the head fragment template i cannot give you more hints for that one. I suspect your title tag in the head fragment is doing something different for the title tag?

Comment: as i guess, the th:include mixes the two content, because there is a th:replace for replacement, but i am not sure... The header fragment does not contain a title tag. The strange thing is i have title tag in the response html, just the localization does not become expanded.

Comment: I updated the question with a new link what contains the main view and the included template too.